# IBM Watson Assistant: How to display/print dictionary( python3) in XML syntax?

Tags: xml, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I want to display some context of the python dictionary as a output in IBM watson.
So for example if I have a dictionary like this

```
{'author': 'Bloomberg News',
 'title': 'India Crisis Worsens; N.Y. Deaths at 5-Month Low: Virus Update',
 'description': 'India Crisis Worsens; N.Y. Deaths at 5-Month Low: Virus Update',
 'url': 'https://www.bloombergquint.com/business/n-y-deaths-at-5-month-low-india-crisis-deepens-virus-update',
 'source': 'Bloomberg | Latest And Live Business',
 'image': None,
 'category': 'business',
 'language': 'en',
 'country': 'us',
 'published_at': '2021-05-02T04:48:26+00:00'}
```

then to print title as a output in IBM Watson Assistant we need to write like this:

```
<?data['title']?>
```

This will give output: India Crisis Worsens; N.Y. Deaths at 5-Month Low: Virus Update

Now if I have a dictionary like this:

```
[{'author': 'BQ Desk',
  'title': 'Coronavirus Updates: India Reports 3.9 Lakh New Covid Cases, 3,689 Deaths',
  'description': 'Coronavirus Updates: India Reports 3.9 Lakh New Covid Cases, 3,689 Deaths',
  'url': 'https://www.bloombergquint.com/coronavirus-outbreak/coronavirus-updates-india-reports-39-lakh-new-covid-cases-3689-deaths',
  'source': 'Bloomberg | Latest And Live Business',
  'image': None,
  'category': 'business',
  'language': 'en',
  'country': 'us',
  'published_at': '2021-05-02T05:15:34+00:00'},
 {'author': None,
  'title': 'Leasebak is geen heilige koe meer',
  'description': 'Managers met een leasebak in je arbeidsvoorwaarden, de vanzelfsprekendheid van de auto van de zaak gaat er vanaf. Als je nu solliciteert, zijn er steeds minder bedrijven die daar zomaar in willen meegaan. Door corona en thuiswerken nemen bedrijven hun mobiliteit nog eens extra onder de loep, zien leaseorganisaties en werkgeversorganisatie AWVN.',
  'url': 'https://www.telegraaf.nl/financieel/1632068442/leasebak-is-geen-heilige-koe-meer',
  'source': 'De Telegraaf - Financieel Overzicht',
  'image': 'https://www.telegraaf.nl/images/1200x630/filters:format(jpeg):quality(80)/cdn-kiosk-api.telegraaf.nl/a64d720a-a9c6-11eb-83a5-02d1dbdc35d1.jpg',
  'category': 'business',
  'language': 'nl',
  'country': 'nl',
  'published_at': '2021-05-02T05:00:00+00:00'},
 {'author': 'Bloomberg News',
  'title': 'India Crisis Worsens; N.Y. Deaths at 5-Month Low: Virus Update',
  'description': 'India Crisis Worsens; N.Y. Deaths at 5-Month Low: Virus Update',
  'url': 'https://www.bloombergquint.com/business/n-y-deaths-at-5-month-low-india-crisis-deepens-virus-update',
  'source': 'Bloomberg | Latest And Live Business',
  'image': None,
  'category': 'business',
  'language': 'en',
  'country': 'us',
  'published_at': '2021-05-02T04:48:26+00:00'},
 {'author': 'FE Online',
  'title': 'Coronavirus in India Live News: PM Modi to meet experts today to review oxygen & medicine availability; India reports 3.92 lakh Covid-19 cases',
  'description': 'Coronavirus Daily Cases and Deaths in India, Covid-19 India Lockdown, May 1 Phase 3 vaccine drive, Day 2 vaccination drive for 18+ years, CoWIN Covid-19 Vaccination Registration, May 2: Prime Minister Narendra Modi is expected to review the human resource situation, in relation to the Covid-19 pandemic, and ways to augment it.',
  'url': 'https://www.financialexpress.com/lifestyle/health/coronavirus-lockdown-in-india-coronavirus-cases-in-india-today-live-covid-19-cowin-vaccine-registration-vaccination-drive-rollout-coronavirus-daily-cases-and-deaths-in-india-covid-19-lockdown-in-del-2/2244047/',
  'source': 'The Financial Express',
  'image': 'https://images.financialexpress.com/2021/05/covid-second-wave.jpg',
  'category': 'business',
  'language': 'en',
  'country': 'us',
  'published_at': '2021-05-02T04:28:25+00:00'},
 {'author': 'Uppsala University',
  'title': 'Newly Discovered Immune Cell Function Vital to Healing May Lead to Treatments for Cancer and Cardiovascular Diseases',
  'description': 'Cardiovascular disease, the most common cause of death, is the result of oxygen deprivation as blood perfusion to affected tissue is prevented. To halt the...The post Newly Discovered Immune Cell Function Vital to Healing May Lead to Treatments for Cancer and Cardiovascular Diseases appeared first on SciTechDaily.',
  'url': 'https://scitechdaily.com/newly-discovered-immune-cell-function-vital-to-healing-may-lead-to-treatments-for-cancer-and-cardiovascular-diseases/',
  'source': 'Scitechdaily | Science Space And Technology News 2017',
  'image': None,
  'category': 'science',
  'language': 'en',
  'country': 'us',
  'published_at': '2021-05-01T22:40:45+00:00'}]
```

Then how to print title name of each article in XML( as the syntax I mentioned above).

```
Desired Output:
Coronavirus Updates: India Reports 3.9 Lakh New Covid Cases, 3,689 Deaths
Leasebak is geen heilige koe meer
India Crisis Worsens; N.Y. Deaths at 5-Month Low: Virus Update
Coronavirus in India Live News: PM Modi to meet experts today to review oxygen & medicine availability; India reports 3.92 lakh Covid-19 cases
Newly Discovered Immune Cell Function Vital to Healing May Lead to Treatments for Cancer and Cardiovascular Diseases
```

Comment: I removed the Python tag. I assume this is in Watson Assistant and not using the Python SDK or a Python client, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your requirements, you may wish to look at the list of methods that can be applied to data, see [Expression language methods within the Watson Assistant Documentation](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-methods). Using these methods you may be able to manipulate the arrays into an output your require.

Alternatively you could call an external REST api that would manipulate the data and return the required output. This external api could be an IBM Cloud function.

Finally and the simplest, you could have a dialog node with multiple responses conditions that correspond to the size of the answer array (list/directory in python). However, this method normally is only suitable for small answer groups, and where the max size of the array/list/directory is know.